# Show hand cursor only onMouseOver item in list

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I am developing app in C# respectively .Net which uses win forms, and I was trying to display the hand cursor only when the mouse is over the item in a list. So in the other words, I don't want to display the hand cursor when the mouse is over the list and it's not over any item in that list.

Is it possible?

Comment: I suppose you are talking about listView?

Comment: yes List view, well I was trying to register mouse over event for item but I wans't succesfull, maybe I had a wrong code but I thought to myself that there has to be easier way...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you specifically want to change cursor when you are over the item or this includes ListViewSubitems?

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should use ListView MouseMove and ListView MouseLeave events and GetItemAt and GetSubItemAt methods that return the items that are on the point where mouse is. You can use this code. I'm not sure that it's optimal but it will serve the purpose.

```
    Cursor standardCursor;
    Cursor differentCursor;
    public Form1()
    {
        standardCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        differentCursor = Cursors.Cross;
    }

    private void listView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Cursor == differentCursor)
            this.Cursor = standardCursor;
    }

    private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = listView1.GetItemAt(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
        if (lvi == null)
        {
            bool found = false;
            int i = 0;
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = null;
            while(!found && i< listView1.Items.Count)
            {
                lvsi = listView1.Items[i].GetSubItemAt(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
                if (lvsi != null)
                    found = true;
                i++;
            }
            if(found)
                this.Cursor = differentCursor;
            else if (this.Cursor == differentCursor)
                this.Cursor = standardCursor;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Cursor = differentCursor;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this was posted, but here is a simple and short Awnser for all of those who come with the same Problem later.

```
private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Y > 2 + (listView1.Items.Count * 20))
        listView1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    else
        listView1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

The '2' is at the top and the '20' stands for the pixels for each item.
You just have to look how much Pixels heigth each Item is.

Answer (score -1):

Click the control on the form and go to the properties. There is a "Cursor" field from which you can select "Hand". This will change the cursor type when scrolling over the control, although I'm not sure how you would do this for individual items on the list.

Comment: "only when the mouse is over the item in a list. So in the other words, I don't want to display the hand cursor when the mouse is over the list and it's not over any item in that list."